# create multiple nested resources with a single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating user permissions for my project, so I created a model called "profile", each "profile" record will represent a module of my proyect, so a "user" has many "profiles", I need to create a form In which I can create multiple profiles to the user and modify all those records in a single form. The form would be like this [image], but I would like to know how I could do to create multiple nested records in a single form and that each one is independent since each record will have fields like the name of the module that identify it, for example "products"

So far I have something like this, but it only shows me a single field:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.fields_for :profiles do |profile| %>
      <%= perfil.hidden_field :Module, value: "Products"  %>
      <%= f.label :Bajas,"Bajas:", class: "control-label" %>
      <%= f.check_box :Bajas %>
    <%end%>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use form-group of div inside @user and change the div like this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |user| %>
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.fields_for :permission, @user.permission do |profile| %>
      <%= perfil.hidden_field :Module, value: "Products"  %>
      <%= f.label :Bajas,"Bajas:", class: "control-label" %>
      <%= f.check_box :Bajas %>
    <%end%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, the example is a single record, but how can I add other records? Which will be almost the same fields with the exception that changes "Module" with another value. Would be just like the image, each row will be in the form and each row will be a record that will contain the field "Module", "Bajas"